# Authenticating with OKTA using .Net core IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'

Tags: .net, okta

I have followed exact steps in https://developer.okta.com/quickstart/#/okta-sign-in-page/dotnet/aspnetcore

here is what I have in my Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OktaDefaults.MvcAuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOktaMvc(new OktaMvcOptions
            {
                OktaDomain = "https://domain.oktapreview.com",
                ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            });
```

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
}
```

I have created the app in OKTA with OpenID Connect**strong text**. when I launch the application I get the following error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'.
```

when I ping https://domain.okta.com/oauth2/defau/v1/keys
I get the following error

```
{"errorCode":"E0000006","errorSummary":"You do not have permission to perform the requested action","errorLink":"E0000006","errorId":"oaeX0BPGXjlQ4qE1emo_gDk4w","errorCauses":[]}
```

I don't know how I am supposed to authenticate with OKTA how does OKTA know which user is trying to authenticate?

Answer (score 3):

When you see such an error "Unable to obtain configuration" the first thing you should do is to check if you set properly identity provider .well-known/openid-configuration and if so to check if you have access to it. Example - https://dev-503639.okta.com/.well-known/openid-configuration.
In case the above are fine in the Startup.cs you should put

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
}
```

to see what is the exact error message.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: **Set OktaMvcOptions.AuthorizationServerId to an empty string**

```
 .AddOktaMvc(new OktaMvcOptions
            {
                OktaDomain = "https://domain.oktapreview.com",
                ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                AuthorizationServerId = String.Empty
            });,
```

I didn't need to do this when connecting to my okta dev account, but I needed to do this when switching to a production account.

If this doesn't help, set IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII to give you a more detailed error message:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
        ....
```

This helped me figure out the first suggestion, as it showed me the URL that the client was trying to hit, and I saw it had an unexpected "/default" in the url.